# C: Glitch?: Sort function NOT working on LINUX (RHEL 6.6), but MAC OS X (10.3)

Tags: c, linux, macos, sorting

I have a program to count the frequency of words from a text file. The node contains three key variables (`frequency`(`int`), `word` (`char[]`) and `next`(`*Node`))

1. Add New word and set frequency to 1
2. If existing word, increment frequency.

Sort Function is Bubble Sort

I created and ran the program in NetBeans & OS X terminal, and the program ran flawlessly without any problem. Giving me correct output.

Can someone please shed a light on what's wrong?

Compiling on Linux/Mac gcc -o file fileName.c

[Entire Code](http://ideone.com/Ln933k)

Sort Fucntion

```
void swap(struct Node *a, struct Node *b)
{   
    int temp = a->frequency;
    a->frequency = b->frequency;
    b->frequency = temp;

    char tempS[50];
    strcpy(tempS, a->word);
    strcpy(a->word,b->word);
    strcpy(b->word,tempS);    
}

void sortList(struct Node *start)
{
    int swapped;
    struct Node *ptr1;
    struct Node *lptr = NULL;

    if (ptr1 == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = start;

        while (ptr1->next != lptr)
        {
            if (ptr1->frequency < ptr1->next->frequency)
            {
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
}
```

Comment: Try this: get rid of `lptr`, and change `while (ptr1->next != lptr)` to `while (ptr1)`, assuming your last node's `next` is NULL.

Comment: @Dmitri Segmentation Fault 11

Comment: Oops... try `while (ptr1->next)`

Comment: @Dmitri Work's perfectly. Now should I delete the question or would you like to post an answer? I am unaware how this part of stackoverflow works. :)

Comment: I can add an answer in a bit.. but with more detail.

Comment: Not that it causes any errors, but the idea of using a linked list is that you can quickly insert or remove elements at any position. A good sorting algorithm would only switch pointers, but your swap function copies the whole content instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each pass of the bubble sort, you need to check each node against the next, and swap if needed.  Since you look at two nodes at a time, in `ptr1` and `ptr1->next`, you need to end the loop when `ptr1->next` is NULL (no next node).  To do that, you can change your loop condition from `while (ptr1->next != lptr)` to just `while (ptr1->next)`, and eliminate `lptr` entirely.

In your code, you were comparing `ptr1->next` to `lptr` instead of `NULL`.  Since `lptr` started off as `NULL`, your first pass was correct -- but at the end of each pass it was set to point at the last node instead, which meant that every loop pass after the first terminated one node early, and the last two nodes wouldn't be swapped even when they needed to be for a proper sort.